# HtmlAgilityPack LoadHtml - Issue with empty P tags

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to load simple html:

```
var html = "<div>something<p></p></div>";

var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
```

After loading this HTML `doc.InnerHtml` outputs this:

```
<div>something<p></div>
```

So as you can see it loses closing P tag and I got messed HTML.

I cannot find any solution for this, can anyone help me please.

Comment: You can use `doc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true` to get `<div>something<p /></div>`

Comment: I marked a dupe, but after more research, I've reopened because that's not a bug. It's a feature (yes, really), and the output is not "messed". In this particular case, the closing tag is optional. Remember HTML isn't XML. [***"The start tag is required. The end tag may be omitted (.......) if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an <a> element."***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) The HTML you posted satisfies these requirements.

Comment: @haim770 Thanks, that resolves my issue. If you want write it as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @spender Thanks to you as well. Yo are right that end tag is optional, but really I would like if HtmlAgilityPack doesn't remove it by self as I consider that as unclear code. Every tag should have end tag or self-closed. Leaving it just opened can cause many issues like I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`OptionWriteEmptyNodes`](https://github.com/jstedfast/HtmlAgilityPack/blob/db6d9ec6114489cc8789a7961f09c8fafc3b25df/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlDocument.cs#L127) flag is what you're looking for:

> Defines if empty nodes must be written as closed during output.

And in your case:

```
doc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;
```

Yields:

```
<div>something<p /></div>
```